# Generating Tokens and converting to c++ code?

Tags: c++, parsing, command, token

I'm working on a user script and engine modifying tool where the user can create scripts of a custom code that are then translated to c++ code, or any others.

For example, user could type `init x` and the generator would provide `x(); ~x();` for example. Or `integer x : 2` turned into `int x = 2`.  How do I do this? Is there any non complicated way to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming that your tool to generate C++ code, is also being written in C++? Do you have a grammar for your custom scripting language? Have you looked into yacc, etc? I don't think there's any truly 'non complicated' way to do it. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671306/A-Cplusplus-Class-Code-Generator) might give you ideas. Also if you could use XML as input, then [Code Synthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) I quite like.

Answer (score 0):

Look into regular expressions. There are tons of resources on the web and most scripting languages support them. It is really easy to do parsing using regular expressions.